# Show that the set $\left\{\sin\frac{1}{2}x,\sin\frac{3}{2}x,\sin\frac{5}{2}x,\ldots\right\}$ is complete on $[0,\pi]$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Show that the set $$\left\{\sin\frac{1}{2}x,\sin\frac{3}{2}x,\sin\frac{5}{2}x,\ldots\right\}$$ is complete on $[0,\pi]$

I think I can change it to $\left\{\sin\left(\frac{2n-1}{2}x\right)\right\}_{n=1}^\infty$

Now I think I'm supposed to show that Parseval's equality holds for every $f \in R[0,\pi]$ which is
$$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi f^2(x)\,dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n^2$$

$$b_n = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi f(x)\sin(nx)\,dx$$
Now I'm not sure what to do.

Edited.

So let $f_0$ denote the odd extensions of $f$ to $[-\pi,\pi]$. We know that $\left\{1, \cos nx, \sin nx\right\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is complete on $[-\pi,\pi]$. So now we have $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n^2 = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f_0^2(x)dx = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi f^2(x)dx$$

$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f_0^2(x)dx = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin\left(\frac{2n-1}{2}x\right) dx = \frac{1}{\pi} \left[\frac{-2\cos(nx - \frac{x}{2})}{2n-1}\right]_{-\pi}^\pi$$

$$= \frac{1}{\pi}\left[\frac{-2\sin(n\pi)}{2n-1} - \frac{-2\sin(n\pi)}{2n-1}\right] = 0$$

Would this be right?

Comment: Please note: $a\sin b$ is coded as a\sin b.  If you write a sin b, you see $a sin b$.  The backslash not only prevents italiciziation but also results in proper spacing.  It is standard usage.  I edited the question accordingly. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Sorry. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: How about this approach: Look at the complete $\sin, \cos$ collection of functions on $[-\pi, \pi]$. You know these are complete. Now take a function on $[0,\pi]$ and extend it so that it is essentially odd on $[-\pi, \pi]$ (maybe some oddities at $x=0$). Then show that the $\cos$ terms are zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can show that

finite linear combinations of $\left\{\sin\frac{1}{2}x,\sin\frac{3}{2}x,\sin\frac{5}{2}x,\ldots\right\}$ is dense in $L^2[0,1]$, then problem is solved. for showing density at the first step use stone-weierstrass theorem and show density respect to $L^{\infty}$ norm and then by the help of inequality $$||g||_{2}\leq||g||_{\infty}$$ which holds for every g belongs finite linear combination of $\left\{\sin\frac{1}{2}x,\sin\frac{3}{2}x,\sin\frac{5}{2}x,\ldots\right\}$ conclude density respect to $L^2$ norm.